# Reclass all values < 0 to -9999 in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, reclassify

I have a tiled raster in a PostGIS table and I would like to change the value of all pixels which have values less than 0 to -9999. How should I do this?

I suspect it involves ST_SetValue and possibly a SQL sub-statement, but I'm not sure how to put these together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comprehensive raster functionality is apparently rather new to PostGIS, but the official reference should be helpful:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/RT_reference.html

I think this is the desired function, with examples:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/RT_ST_Reclass.html

And for constructing the reclassarg, the docs are a little hazier:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reclassarg.html

I think it should be something along the lines of:

'(-999999-0):-9999,[0-999999]:0-999999'